# Flutter iOS - redirect stalling in 3rd party website or my custom redirect page

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, deep-linking, flutter-ios

#### Description

Using the [oauth2_client package](https://github.com/teranetsrl/oauth2_client) to connect to a [3rd party API](https://api.youneedabudget.com/#authentication). So I created a custom client, set up a webserver (since the 3rd party API requires the redirect url to be HTTPS), and configured what I thought were the right files. Its been a solid week of attempting this and I'm at the end of the rope, not sure what to look into next or if this is a bug? I doubt it but this is a big obstacle.

Behavior: I'm using implicit grant flow for oauth2. When clicking through the 3rd party auth, it hangs on that 3rd party app website after I click "authorize".
[image: oauth hangs on 3rd party website]

I followed some [flutter-ios documentation here for deep linking](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking#enable-deep-linking-on-ios) as well.  Testing it using "xcrun simctl openurl booted
[https://www.insightsforynab.com/oauth/redirect.html"](https://www.insightsforynab.com/oauth/redirect.html%22) works just fine, it redirects to my app.

Previous to adding true deep linking with iOS, it got through the 3rd party auth page but then browser would remain open at my redirect.html page.
[image]

I do have my redirect URL correctly labeled on the 3rd party website:
[image: redirect uri on 3rd party website]

I just want to close the damn browser after they authenticate  I can see on the 3rd party website that they ARE receiving the auth request from the my dummy user and adding it appropriately. Just can't quite cross the finish line.

My questions:

- What am I missing?
- How do I debug an in-app browser using flutter? The network calls seems to be outside the actual app so I cannot view them with DevTools network viewer

#### Code Snippets:

The flutter button component calling oauth helper:

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                AccessTokenResponse resp = await oAuth2Helper.fetchToken();
                //print(resp.accessToken);
              },
```

custom client for 3rd party API --

```
import "package:oauth2_client/oauth2_client.dart";

class YNABClient extends OAuth2Client {
  YNABClient({required String redirectUri, required String customUriScheme})
      : super(
            authorizeUrl:
                'https://app.youneedabudget.com/oauth/authorize', //3rd party API
            tokenUrl:
                'https://app.youneedabudget.com/oauth/authorize', //3rd party API
            redirectUri: redirectUri,
            customUriScheme: customUriScheme);
}
```

Instantiating the client using https as the customUriScheme and my own redirect file on webserver. Then calling the oauth helper and sending in custom client. Using implicit grant flow here --

```
YNABClient client = YNABClient(
    redirectUri: 'https://www.insightsforynab.com/oauth/redirect.html',
    customUriScheme: 'https');

OAuth2Helper oAuth2Helper = OAuth2Helper(
  client,
  grantType: OAuth2Helper.IMPLICIT_GRANT,
  clientId: APIKeys.clientKey,
);
```

iOS info.plist (the parallel of androidManifest.xml) --

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>www.insightsforynab.com/oauth/redirect.html</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>https</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

iOS runner.entitlements (to enable deep linking)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:insightsforynab.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Apple app site association file on my webserver:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "[team-id].com.insights-for-ynab",
        "paths": [ "/oauth/redirect.html"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: For now, I ended up switching away from this Oauth package and instead using an in-app webview where I was able to handle the Implicit Flow just fine and get the access_token. Still using HTTPS and I dispose of the webview when the auth flow is done.